# I can't set 0777 as file permissions because owner/group is 48 48

Tags: php, permissions, directory, laravel

I am trying to create a folder chmod it to 777 but I'm unable to it. It always reverts changes to:

```
File Permissions: 341 Owner/Group: 48 48
```

It only happens when I try to create a folder using PHP. I use Laravel's mkdir function. (Ref: http://laravel.com/api/class-Laravel.File.html) It works normally if I create folder with FTP.

As asked on other (probably duplicate) topics;

This script outputs:

```
<?php echo "UID = " . getmyuid() . ", User = " . get_current_user(); ?>
//Output: UID = 502, User = TestUser
```

I use directadmin as panel and `safe_mode is off.`

What should I do?

Comment: Does the folder which you're creating these folders in have the right permissions set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your httpd.conf file change those 2 lines to any user and group you want.

```
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch...
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User _www
Group _www
```

then restart your apache on linux like system by typing  ;

**sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart**

on windows I dont know.